# Intermittent 401 UnAuthorized error in TLS Hand Shake

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, tls1.2, tls1.0

We have developed two different Web API application assume that A and B and both are hosted in Same servers(Server X & Y) and we are using Load Balancer. 
A connects with B for getting the Data and the DB interactions are done in B Application.

So If application A wants to get any data it has to call application B. We are using Mutual TLS(TLS 1.2) concept for authentication.

To call B from A we need to pass client certificate for authentication. The Certificate based authentication are done in IIS level.

Sometimes the Handshake is happening properly and we are able to get data. 
But intermittently we are getting 401 UnAuthorized issue even if we are passing valid SYST client certificate.

We verified both the server's IIS configuration as well everything appears same.

So we were unable to understand what is the actual cause for this Intermittent behavior. 
Can Someone help us what could be the possible reason.

Comment: I help somebody yesterday with an intermittent http connection.  The person was trying to use a net xml library to read an xml from a http URL.  I fund that if I opened two xml documents reading from the same URL I always got a 401 error.  It wasn't intermittent.  You may have the same issue that you are not closing a http connection before trying to open the same URL a second time.

Comment: @jdweng are not accessing any of the files.We are just  directly hitting the database.

Comment: You are not directly hitting the database. You are connecting to a HTTP service.  It  is either you are trying to connect multiple times or you have a timeout which is too small.  You may want to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture a good connection and bad connection and compare results.